# 'Would' to indicate that the information given is not absolutely certain

Tags: conditionals, would

Page 60 of *Learner English: A Teacher's Guide to Interference* gives two example sentences that the author claims are ungrammatical uses of "would" when indicating uncertainty.

> **The hijackers **would** be members of the extremist group*. (instead of ...*are thought to be* or *are allegedly* . . .)
>
> **According to Opposition leaders, the decision **would** have been taken*, (instead of . . . *the decision was taken*.)

Are both examples really ungrammatical though?

Comment: Are you really asking about grammaticality?

Comment: You can write lies, wild theories, fancied outcomes, unsubstantiated opinions ... and do so perfectly grammatically. (eg _The moon will be made of green cheese after undergoing a makeover in the next few days._) The contexts need extending, GJC, and the question refining.

Comment: These are both fine if *would* is used to mean *to be expected/assumed to*. *The decision was expected to have been taken...* *The hijackers were assumed to be members...*

Comment: Why are we talking about French? If this teachers' guide occasions so many questions, get a new one.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Speakers of Romance languages like French, Spanish, and Portuguese often use their synthetic "future" and synthetic "conditional" inflections for probability. For example, Spanish (or Portuguese, with slightly different spellings) can use *será Marcos* to mean it's probably him and *sería Marcos* to mean the same but more remotely/less likely. French does this, too, but it may be that native speakers of French use this style more often than those of English do with our analytic (periphrastic, multiword) futures and conditionals.

Comment: Thank you. Though I'm no longer surprised about the oddities of any English modal.

Answer (score 4):

The textbook is correct. That particular use of the conditional, while idiomatic in French, doesn't exist in English. The sentences are grammatical but don't mean what's intended.

Here’s a [reference on the French usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/que-signifie-le-conditionnel-dans-le-titre-dun-article-de-presse) from our sister site for French. In short, you can use it to indicate that something has been alleged but is not yet verified.

> Edward Snowden would have accepted Venezuela's offer of asylum.

In English, this can have one of two meanings:

1. If a given situation had arisen, Snowden would have accepted the offer, but in fact it did not arise, and he did not accept the offer.
2. If what a certain person said is true, then it would have the consequence that Snowden would accepted the offer; but it's not known whether that antecedent is true.

This latter is only subtly different from 3., which the sentence *can't* mean:

3. A certain person claimed that Snowden accepted the offer.

Whereas that's what the French sentence means.

Comment: The [OED disagrees with you](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229051).

Comment: @tchrist That's a massive article. Would you mind pointing to the definition you found that describes the use we're talking about?

Comment: I'm thinking of senses 22d and 15b. This became too long to explain in a comment, so I have given that as an answer.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks. Those are pretty fair, but imo it's clear it can't have those senses in the journalistic context quoted. In any case, it certainly can't be reasonably interpreted in exactly the same way the French should be — that it has been alleged, that there has been some noise to this effect. It would be misinterpreted in this context.

Comment: This is the right answer. The examples presented in the question are literal translations of the French sentences *Les pirates de l'air feraient partie du groupe terroriste* and *D'après les leaders de l'opposition, la décision serait prise*, but, despite being grammatical English, do not convey the meaning they have in French.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not necessarily grammatically incorrect in all possible circumstances. It needs more setup than the examples you've shown probably provide, but we do often use *will* and *would* to express likelihood in English.

For example, imagine that there’s a knock at the door. You think you know who it is, so you say as much. Either of these works just fine for this:

1. That **will be** John.
   (a guess about a present event that’s probably true, with more assurance than in case 2)
2. That **would be** John.
   (*also* a guess about a present event that’s probably true, but just not quite so likely as in case 1)

There is perhaps a small nuance of difference between the two: the second version with *would* means the speaker is somewhat less certain about their guess than the first version with *will*. That’s because using the past tense  is a way of distancing, so that makes it less likely than the present tense. (Here *will* is that verb’s present tense and *would* its past tense.)

When it’s an event remote in time that you’re describing, such as if you had heard the phone ring last night, then we normally use a ***perfect*** form to show that it was an earlier event than right now:

3. That **will have been** John. 
   (a guess about a past event that’s probably true, with more assurance than in case 4)
4. That **would have been** John. 
   (*also* a guess about a past event that’s probably true, but just not quite so likely as in case 3)

Here again the latter version with *would* is saying that the speaker considers it a little less likely a guess than former version with *will*.

You can see in these 4 examples sentence I just gave how we’re actually using (A) the present–*versus*–past distinction for **likelihood**, and (B) the not-perfect–*versus*–perfect distinction for **remoteness** in time, which is  exactly what tense normally means in regular verbs that aren’t modals. But modals are funny.

---

## References

The OED mentions using *will/would* this way in its sense [22d](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/229051#eid14506608):

> **23d.** Expressing the past likelihood of an action or fact with little or no future reference, as in *would be* ‘probably or presumably was’. Now usually in *would have* followed by the past participle. Cf. [15b](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/229051#eid14504247).

Among the provided citations are:

> - 1857   E. C. Gaskell *Life C. Brontë* I. iv. 79 
>     ‘Of the two younger ones..I have very slight recollections, save that one..was quite the pet nursling of the school.’ This last would be Emily.
> - 1906   R. H. Benson *Richard Raynal* v. 91  
>    It would be about half an hour before the King's dinner-time..that Master Richard came again to the hall.
> - 1909   E. H. Burton *Life Bp. Challoner* I. ii. 12  
>    The last of the Douay martyrs..had suffered but one year previously. Some of the priests living at Douay would have known this martyr personally.
> - 2008   *New Scientist* 14 June 51/1  
>    People in this region would have seen an entire black disc in front of the sun, blocking out 95 per cent of the sun's light—an unforgettable sight.

And sense 15b starts with:

> **15b.** Expressing the likeliness of an action or fact with little or no future reference: will prove or turn out to, will be found on inquiry to; may be supposed to. [...]

The verb *will/would* is **almost infinitely more complex** than almost anyone gives it credit for. That’s why [the OED provides 110 senses](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/229051) for this verb (94 main senses, 16 subentry senses) and 942 citations.